# TypeScript: type return of wrapper function to return type of function wrapped in closure

Tags: typescript

I have some iffy functions which need to be wrapped in `try-catch`-blocks. However, if they fail, I'm fine with having `null` as their return value. So, I decided to create a wrapper function which accepts a closure, and executes it. However, I'm struggling with the typing.

```
async function myStringFunction(myStringParam: string): Promise<string> {
    return Promise.resolve(`${myStringParam} is great!`)
}

async function myNumberFunction(myNumberParam: number): Promise<number> {
    return Promise.resolve(myNumberParam + 1)
}

async function myArrayFunction(myArrayParam: string[]): Promise<string[]> {
    myArrayParam.push("another item")
    return Promise.resolve(myArrayParam)
}

async function doStuffOrReturnNull(myFunctionParam: () => any) {
    try {
        return await myFunctionParam()
    }
    catch(error) {
        return null
    }
}

async function mainFunction() {
    const myString = await doStuffOrReturnNull(() => myStringFunction("my input string"))
    const myNumber = await doStuffOrReturnNull(() => myNumberFunction(42))
    const myArray = await doStuffOrReturnNull(() => myArrayFunction(["whatever"]))
    console.log(myString, myNumber, myArray)
}

mainFunction()
```

The problem is, you guessed it: `() => any`. That way, I'm losing all typing information which the functions inside the closure has.

How can I type it so that the actual typing gets passed through?

In reality, I'm wrapping a third-party library here. So, the functions and return values could change over time. Hard-coding anything is absolutely out of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture the type of the result using a type parameter:

```
async function doStuffOrReturnNull<T>(myFunctionParam: () => T) {
    try {
        return await myFunctionParam()
    }
    catch(error) {
        return null
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-RDZAANJ3yoQH2uwATVF6SBuBEA)